# How can use BCC in sending multiple mail in PHP mail function

Tags: php

I am trying to send mail to multiple recipient without them seeing each others email address

this is what I have done so far

```
//my variable $mailto got all the emails from the database
$mailto = preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($mailto));  

$headers = 'FROM: COMPANY INC <support@admin.com>\r\n';
        $headers .= 'BBC'.$mailto."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-  8859-1\r\n';

mail($mailto, "MY TITle", $mailbody, $headers);
```

Comment: so what exactly is your question, what is your problem?

Comment: The code is not seeding any email. The previous code that I had without BBC send email to all recipient but they all see each others email address. I want this current code to send email to multiple recipients, without showing them all recipients email (or hide the email address to all the recipient)

Comment: You need to set at least one recipient to send the mail TO.

Comment: You can simply concatenate all recipient emails by comma into one BCC string and send a single email for one go to all, and they will not see each other email addresses

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the wrong header. There is no `BBC`, and you're missing a colon.

try

```
    $headers .= 'BCC: '.$ml."\r\n";
```

Comment: its still not working, the $ml has emails in this format $ml(mail1@soso.com,(mail2@soso.com,(mail3@soso.com)